# Azure App Services - Enforce Client Certificates

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We recently had a security audit on our Azure environment and one finding was that we should enforce the use of client certificates (TLS mutual auth) on any app service or function app.  There is no Azure policy that we can find to force an admin to use a client cert when setting up their Azure app that we can find.  Is there any way to enforce this?  Ideally, the app service or function app would not work unless client certificate mode were set to "Require".   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- To enforce client certificate to Azure WebApp or Azure Function you need to set `client certificate mode` to `require` in `Configuration`
- Add `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = *` to load all certificates or `thumbprint` of certificate in `Enviroment variables`.

For reference check this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).

Check my SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77043286/azure-certificate-authorization-instead-of-secret-key/77051509#77051509) for reference.

[image]

[image]

This worked for me.

I have used and deployed a sample Blazor app from VS 2022.

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: appreciate the comment, but we want to force any web app that gets created to use a client cert, I understand  how to do it in the gui by setting it to require, but is there any way to force the issue where a developer would have to set the web app to use a cert otherwise the web app would not function?

Comment: @user2600700, AFAIK, unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to enforce the `client certificate mode` to require using code. you can access the certificate using app code, which is given in the reference document link which I have added in the answer.

Comment: thats what I figured, much appreciated